# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint

Tags: java, android, android-location, android-maps

I'm trying to get latitude and longitude from address through this method:-

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress){

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address;
    GeoPoint p1 = null;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
        if (address==null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location=address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

        return p1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I got this **error**:-

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint

What am I missing here?

My full **error**:-

> Process: breamex.happy_week_end, PID: 22803                                                                        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint;
>                                                                               at
>   breamex.happy_week_end.search.SearchActivity.getLocationFromAddress(SearchActivity.java:439)
>                                                                               at
>   breamex.happy_week_end.search.SearchActivity.search(SearchActivity.java:357)
>                                                                               at
>   breamex.happy_week_end.search.SearchActivity.access$000(SearchActivity.java:76)
>                                                                               at
>   breamex.happy_week_end.search.SearchActivity$1.onClick(SearchActivity.java:189)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app

My full **Gradle**:-

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':stepper')
    compile project(':slider')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: post your complete error log and gradle file

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs  what the gradle will do for you btw i didn't used it?, and this the main error, no more useful things ?

Comment: You can't define this is an exact error.This error may be caused by some other reason. So post your complete error log.

Comment: We are asking your gradle file to check your libraries.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs updated

Comment: Check the answer, I'll be happy if your error resolved

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs i just changed GeoPoint and used another way, and it work now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you removed any library from your project or you made any other changes. But as per your error log 100% that is multi dex issue. Anyway is good to hear your problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include **multiDex** in your application.
See the below error in your error log.

```
ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app
```

Add this to your dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

In your Gradle add `multiDexEnabled true`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true    // add this line
    }
    ...
}
```

In your manifest add **multiDex** application class.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then clean and rebuild your project.

Hope it hleps:)